# How to determine in a fast way how many times to perform an n-1 operation for any odd number?

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers, rules

One of my programs does the following for odd numbers:

1. If the number is odd, subtract 1 from it.
2. If the number is even, divide it by 2.
3. Do until the final answer is 0.
4. Returns the number of the time minus 1, called subtimes.
   For example,the subtimes of 21 is 3.
   Here's a simple piece of code that shows how it works

```
def getsubtimes(num):
    subtimes=0
    while num!=0:
        if num%2==0:
            num/=2
        else:
            num-=1
            subtimes+=1
    return subtimes
```

I counted all the odd numbers between 3 and 1023, and then I did a visualization:
[image: visualization between 3 and 1023]
This is my visual code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
subtimesAim=10
x=[i for i in range(3,2**subtimesAim+1,2)]
y=[getsubtimes(i) for i in x]
specialAim=[i for i in range(2,subtimesAim+1)]
specialNum=[2**i-1 for i in specialAim]
plt.plot(x,y,specialNum,specialAim)
plt.show()
```

The blue line is the subtimes required for these odd numbers. And then I also noticed that odd numbers like **2^n-1** always seem to have more subtimes, so I connected all the odd numbers like 2^n-1.
The structure of the graph above looks pretty regular, but what is the pattern? Does it have to do with 2^n? If you're given an odd number, is there any way to get the subtimes of that number faster than by writing a piece of code that computes it step by step?

Comment: Your algorithm is called `popcount`.

Comment: Number of '1' bits in the binary representation of your number?

Comment: Whatever algorithm you use, this will need log2(n) operations, more or less hidden in you code...

Comment: @KellyBundy It takes log2(n) divisions by 2 (plus some subtractions of 1) to get to 0 with this code, so it's O(log2(n)).

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Do you mean Theta(log2(n))? What data type as input are you thinking of?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Oh, actually even for `int` it takes Omega(log n). Because of the `%2`. Then possibly again for the `-=1`. After that, it's O(1) because the division will (try to) make it a `float`, which either crashes right away or limits  the rest by a constant.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Although what you said sounds like something different, like if they had used `//=`. But then it wouldn't be O(log n) but Theta(n²), as the int operations take linear time.

Comment: Can you please add the code for the visualization?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Well yes, I realize that's true.

Comment: @AcK Sure,I've already added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is wrong to do `num/=2` as (in Pyton 3) this will make `num` a float instead of an int, thereby limiting the precision and causing inaccurate results for big numbers. You should maintain the int data type by using `num//=2` or `num>>=1`.

> I connected all the odd numbers like 2^n-1. The structure of the graph above looks pretty regular, but what is the pattern? Does it have to do with 2^n?

The number of "subtimes" corresponds to the count of 1 bits in the binary representation of the number. In the case of numbers in the form 2−1 this corresponds to the number of bits that are necessary to represent the number, which are all 1. For instance 2<sup>10</sup>−1 is 1111111111 in binary representation, and the corresponding number of subtimes is thus 10 (cf. the last ,  in your graph). That 10 is the exponent given to 2 in the expression 2−1.

The graph that you have drawn will hit the blue bars when =2−1, and to make  a function of , we can rewrite:

=2−1
      +1=2
      log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub>(+1)=

So the function that will follow the same fixation points is () = log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub>(+1)

> If you're given an odd number, is there any way to get the subtimes of that number faster than by writing a piece of code that computes it step by step?

If with "odd" you specifically mean the forms of 2−1 that you mentioned earlier, then you can use:

```
def getsubtimes(n):
    return n.bit_length()
```

But this will only give the desired result for numbers that are one less than a power of 2.

For the generic case (any unsigned integer), you could get the binary representation of the number as a string of "0" and "1" and count the "1"s:

```
def getsubtimes(n):
    return f"{n:b}".count('1')
```

or, similar:

```
def getsubtimes(n):
    return bin(n).count('1')
```

And since Python 3.10 you can use [`bit_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count):

```
def getsubtimes(n):
    return n.bit_count()
```

As `//2` does not have a constant time complexity, your (corrected) code has a time complexity of log², while this solution has a time complexity [of log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793388/time-complexity-of-bin-in-python).

The difference is significant but the difference in actual running time for practical inputs will be more due to the fact that this solution doesn't have a loop executing *in Python code*, but has all the looping happening in compiled code, making it run faster.

Of course, when you use one of the above one-liner functions, you don't really need the `getsubtimes` function wrapper, and could use the function used as implementation directly (i.e. `bit_count` if you have Python 3.10+). This will save you some more running time.

Comment: Or `getsubtimes = int.bit_count`.

Comment: `int.bit_count()` is fairly new, since 3.10.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Almost 500 days old. Some people might have it already.

Comment: Probably a lot of people, but some of us reactionaries are still hanging on to 3.9 :)

Comment: [Small benchmark](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBNCsIwEEZx4WZOMbskUAUrFBE8S2lrWgN2EtLpwrO46UYP5WlMUsWfLF8-3sx817u78MnSNN1Gble7x2LZetsjm14bRtM76xm9drpigEHz6PCAQgg46hY7zcNYx-ywkaT2gOH5EPKEtK4Nl40diaUC-IrmwWCIP_8AFFBRFBDF0FqPZUigr6jTcpu8ETbV-Ry5-Jsrsh-URzTvwsHbG5LzATIKMkxXKJUCzodNJGfJHdEM1NzGq5R3OU8): wrapped `int.bitcount` like you did took 120 ns for a number in their range, while assigned like I did took 40 ns.

Comment: Yes, there is no reason for a function wrapper when the function is a one-liner.

Comment: Well, depends. Encapsulating the steps of `f"{n:b}".count('1')` in a function can still be nice to have. `int.bit_count` differs as it doesn't have any extra steps.